# Multiple simultaneous browser sessions

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, privacy

I'm looking for a chrome or firefox plugin that allows me to have windows with different sessions. It's a bit like chrome's [incognito](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464) works: if you open an incognito window, it won't share the cookies with the "normal" browser window.

I'm searching for a solution that allows me to create several windows (incognito only allows two: the main window and the incognito window), each with a different session (i.e., without sharing cookies between browser windows).

Any thoughts? I'm using OSX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome has this functionality baked in: http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/multi-profiles

If you hit settings (`command-,` on OSX), you'll see a "Users" section. Simply add users to generate multiple profiles within Chrome, each of which containing its own cookie jar, history, etc.

Comment: Now that I'm trying it more, it's not *exactly* what I was looking for, because I'd prefer if some data was shared between users (like the bookmarks, url auto-completion, etc.), but still, it's pretty close to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think you could do this by using different configuration directories. I don't know about OSX but on linux you can copy .config/google-chrome/ and create .config/google-chrome1/, .config/google-chrome2/, .config/google-chrome3/, etc.
You can start each separate browser with **google-chrome --user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome1/**.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple Firefox profiles simultaneously with the

```
-p -no-remote
```

command line argument. This will prompt you to select a profile to run without interfering with other Firefox instances.

[image: choose user profile]

---

More information:

- [Command line arguments | MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)
- [Opening a new instance ... with another profile | MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile)

Comment: And you can have shortcuts with specific shortcuts with `-p "profilename"`.

Answer (score -1):

Mozilla's (relatively) new [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) plugin can do this.