# How to open multiple browsers without sharing cookies to each other?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cookies

I want to ask how can I open a browser (doesn't matter which to be honest, as long as it has the main features of each browser) multiple times without sharing the cookies and other stuff between each other.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple simultaneous browser sessions](http://superuser.com/questions/396918/multiple-simultaneous-browser-sessions), [How to launch standalone browser session?](http://superuser.com/questions/453830/how-to-launch-standalone-browser-session?rq=1)

Comment: @techie007 I'll give it a try soon and let you know if it still works.

Comment: In IE, you can use the menu option File > New session

Answer (score 0):

each browser has its own cookies, just use different browsers IE, FireFox.. etc

Comment: Not enough. I need more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

I use the incognito feature of chrome and private browsing feature of firefox frequently to avoid the sharing of cookies.  For example, if I want to be logged into Google Drive on multiple accounts at the same time I can open Chrome in incognito mode and it doesnt share it's cookies.

If that doesnt give you enough sessions you could try some of the extensions out there like [swap my cookies.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/swap-my-cookies/dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama)